# Ruby - rake db:migrate Access Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

I keep receiving the following error but I know the access credential are correct.

```
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'username'@'156.LocalIP' (using password: YES)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
(in C:/Users/username/Desktop/MySite)
```

I am also trying to access a eHost cpanel mysql Database. I am kind of expecting 'username'@'remoteIP' instead of the 'localIP'.

I am using the following in my database.yml for production.

```
production: 
  adapter: mysql
  pool: 5
  database: "felixDB"
  username: "username"
  password: "pw"
  host: "108.hostIP"
  port: 3306
```

Looks like others have similar problems, trying to use there solutions but nothing works yet.

Any clues on what I may be doing wrong? Please ask questions if more information is needed.

Comment: This is what you need right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911976/problem-with-rake-dbmigrate)

Comment: Ok im checking it out. I will follow up!

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: I am trying, problem is I cannot grant any rights to a user from another location. I want to give all rights to user@localhost to have access to my remote mysql db. Working with support with cpanel to see what I can do.